# How to pronounce "Jupyter" e.g. in "Jupyter Notebook"?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have heard a lot of people saying "Jupyter" with "py" as in Python, while others say "Jupyter", with "py" as in the name of the planet.
So, what is the most correct form?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fortunately, there are many videos and podcasts with Fernando Pérez and Brian Granger, core developers of IPython/Project Jupyter and we can easily check them. They say Jupyter with "py" as in the name of the planet.
Here is an example of Fernando Perez talking about Jupyter, in [PLOTCON 2016: Fernando Perez, The architecture of Jupyter](https://youtu.be/cc2hHjARNTY?t=314).

Comment: Planet Jupiter is spelled with an "i", which makes it seem logical for me to pronounce Jupyter with the "py" as in Python.

Comment: I think the best proof of this argument is the video from the [SciPy 2014 Lightning Talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDrhn0-r9Eg&t=4m10s)